# Hide img carousel box if empty

Tags: php, html

How do I hide the div if the user only select 9 images and what I want is to hide other image div or else it will appear a blank box if no image is added. It is a carousel.

```
<h2><?php echo $title ?></h2>

<!-- Swiper -->

<div class="swiper-container">
<div class="swiper-wrapper">
<div class="swiper-slide"><img style="width:100%; height:100%" src="
<?php echo $Image_Input_1 ?>"></div>

<div class="swiper-slide"><img style="width:100%; height:100%" src="
<?php echo $Image_Input_2 ?>"></div>

<div class="swiper-slide"><img style="width:100%; height:100%" 
src="<?php echo $Image_Input_3 ?>"></div>

<div class="swiper-slide"><img style="width:100%; height:100%" 
src="<?php echo $Image_Input_4 ?>"></div>

<div class="swiper-slide"><img style="width:100%; height:100%" 
src="<?php echo $Image_Input_5 ?>"></div>

<div class="swiper-slide"><img style="width:100%; height:100%" 
src="<?php echo $Image_Input_6 ?>"></div>

<div class="swiper-slide"><img style="width:100%; height:100%" 
src="<?php echo $Image_Input_7 ?>"></div>

<div class="swiper-slide"><img style="width:100%; height:100%" 
src="<?php echo $Image_Input_8 ?>"></div>

<div class="swiper-slide"><img style="width:100%; height:100%" 
src="<?php echo $Image_Input_9 ?>"></div>

<div class="swiper-slide"><img style="width:100%; height:100%" 
src="<?php echo $Image_Input_10 ?>"></div>
</div>

<!-- Add Pagination -->
<div class="swiper-pagination"></div>
<!-- Add Arrows -->
<div class="swiper-button-next"></div>
<div class="swiper-button-prev"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please clerify your question. How does a user select images? You're only showing us how the images are displayed. Nothing else.

Comment: It is included with xml file, users can choose whether 1 or 10 images to be display once field type created in xml file, I created a limit amount of image to be display is 10 in this code.
For example, users choose 3 images and what I expect is it will hide the blanks space of the 7 left when it is empty.

Comment: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/18153829) your question and show us an example of such an XML file. We can't show you how to hide images based on settings inside an XML file without that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just put your images in array and loop it using `foreach`

Here's how you do it:

**Put your images in array**

```
$image_inputs = array(
    $Image_Input_1,
    $Image_Input_2,
    $Image_Input_3,
    $Image_Input_4,
    $Image_Input_5,
    $Image_Input_6,
    $Image_Input_7,
    $Image_Input_8,
    $Image_Input_9,
    $Image_Input_10
);
```

**And loop it using foreach**

```
<?php foreach($image_inputs as $image):?>
<div class="swiper-slide">
    <img style="width:100%; height:100%; <?php echo (empty($image) ? 'display:none;' : ''); ?> " src="<?php echo $image; ?>">
</div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

**Here is the whole code**

```
<?php 

$image_inputs = array(
    $Image_Input_1,
    $Image_Input_2,
    $Image_Input_3,
    $Image_Input_4,
    $Image_Input_5,
    $Image_Input_6,
    $Image_Input_7,
    $Image_Input_8,
    $Image_Input_9,
    $Image_Input_10
);
?>

<div class="swiper-container">
<div class="swiper-wrapper">


  <?php foreach($image_inputs as $image):?>
  <?php if(empty($image)){ }else{ ?>
  <?php echo '<div class="swiper-slide"><img style="width:100%; 
  height:100%" src="'.$image.'"></div>';}  ?>

<!-- Add Pagination -->
<div class="swiper-pagination"></div>
<!-- Add Arrows -->
<div class="swiper-button-next"></div>
<div class="swiper-button-prev"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: How is this answering the question? He's asking how to hide divs on user selection. Not how to display blank images. You shouldn't answer this question to begin with since OP doesn't show how a user selection takes place at all

Comment: He also just want to appear to div as a blank box. He has two option. use a blank image or just do a css for div

Comment: _what I want is to hide other image div or else it will appear a blank box_ <-- Read carefully. He wants to hide the other image divs because it would appear as a blank box if he doesn't. He's not asking to show a blank box instead.

Comment: @icecub I just edited my answer. I just added a condition in foreach loop

Comment: Much better :) But untill OP clears up his question, there's no giving any good answer. Yours just as good as it's gonna get with the information provided. I'll keep an eye on this one for a while. See if OP responds. If not I'll at least give you a +1 for your efford

Comment: As you can see, he wants to hide images based on a XML file. So you're going to have to change your answer completely once he gives us an example of it. That's why the question was simply to unclear to answer :P

Comment: Haha. I guess I was just to excited to answer since I'm not doing anything in office right now.

Answer (score 1):

You can check if the $Image_Input_10 has value. If none, then hide the div. See my code below which is added on your swiper-container div

```
 <div class="swiper-container" <?php if(isset($Image_Input_10)){ echo 'style="display:none;"';} ?>>
```

Comment: Please use `empty()` instead of `isset()` in your code. `isset()` will simply check if the variable exists. Not if it's empty or not.